# Classes included within main() method

Tags: c++, class, include, program-entry-point

If I have some code like

```
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
#include "Class1.H"
#include "Class2.H"
...

}
```

Generally the main() method is the starting point of every application and the content within main() is to be executed. Am I right in the assumption that the content of all classes included into main() will be executed when main() is started?

greetings
Streight

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main().

Comment: possible duplicate of [#include inside the main () function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874002/include-inside-the-main-function)

Comment: No, the question doesn't answer my question. I just want to know if the classes included in main() are executed.

Comment: Classes define types. Classes are not executed. They can provide functions that other functions (e.g., `main`) can call.

Comment: So the methods inside the in main() included classes are executed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no, **NO**.

First of all, you don't `#include` a file within a function.  You `#include` a file at the beginning of a file, before other declarations.  OK, you *can* use `#include` anywhere, but you really just shouldn't.

Second, `#include` doesn't *execute* anything.  It's basically just a copy-paste operation.  The contents of the `#include`d file are (effectively) inserted exactly where you put the `#include`.

Third, if you're going to learn to program in C++, please consider picking up one of our [recommended texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

---

You commented:

> I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and
>   inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I
>   assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in
>   main()

That may be the case, and I don't doubt that the classes have the right structure to be called from `main`.  The problem is `main` will be malformed after the `#include`s because you'll have local class definitions and who knows what else within `main`.

Consider this.  If you have a header:

### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo (const std::string& val)
  :
    mVal (val)
  {
  }
private:
  std::string mVal;
};

#endif
```

And you try to include this in main:

### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  #include "foo.h"
}
```

After preprocessing the `#include` directive, the resulting file that the compiler will try to compile will look like this:

### preprocessed main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    #ifndef FOO_H
    #define FOO_H

    class Foo
    {
    public:
      Foo (const std::string& val)
      :
        mVal (val)
      {
      }
    private:
      std::string mVal;
    };

    #endif
}
```

This is all kinds of wrong. One, you can't declare local classes like this.  Two, `Foo` won't be "executed", as you seem to assume.

main.cpp should look like this instead:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main()

Comment: Ok, I have checked the included classes/files now and their is no class declaration within them. There are just methods listed inside the included files without class declaration. So it works like I have assumed. Since you brought up this argument so clearly I will give your answer the solved flag

Answer (score 4):

`#define` and `#include` are just textual operations that take place during the `'preprocessing'` phase of compilation, which is technically an optional phase. So you can mix and match them in all sorts of ways and as long as your preprocessor syntax is correct it will work.

However if you do redefine macros with `#undef` your code will be hard to follow because the same text could have different meanings in different places in the code.

For custom types typedef is much preferred where possible because you can still benefit from the type checking mechanism of the compiler and it is less error-prone because it is much less likely than `#define` macros to have unexpected side-effects on surrounding code.

Jim Blacklers Answer @ [#include inside the main () function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874002/include-inside-the-main-function)

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main().

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid code like this. `#include` directive inserts contents of the file in its place.
You can simulate the result of your code by copy-pasting file content from Class1.H and Class2.H inside the main function.

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main().

Comment: I've looked the OpenFoam samples and they are including files directly inside main. So if it is library requirement you don't have much options, but in general it is not a good practice to include files directly in some scope (function, namespace, class, etc...).

Answer (score 2):

Includes do not belong into any function or class method body, this is not a good idea to do.
No code will be executed unless you instantiate one of your classes in your header files.

Code is executed when:

1. Class is instantiated, then it's constructor method is called and the code inside the method is executed.
2. If there are variables of a class type inside your instantiated class, they will too run their constructors.
3. When you call a class method.

Try this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class A
    { public:
        A() { cout << "A constructor called" << endl; }
    };
    // A has no instances
    class B
    { public:
        B() { cout << "B constructor called" << endl; }
        void test() { cout << "B test called" << endl; }
    } bbb;
    // bbb will be new class instance of B
    bbb.test(); // example call of test method of bbb instance
    B ccc;      // another class instance of B
    ccc.test(); // another call, this time of ccc instance
}
```

When you run it, you'll observe that:

1. there will be no instance of class A created. Nothing will be run from class A.
2. if you intantiate bbb and ccc, their constructors will be run. To run any other code you must first make a method, for example `test` and then call it.

Comment: `#include` is merely a preprocessor directive. It is irrelevant whether this occurs within a function or not.

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main().

Answer (score 1):

This is an openFoam syntax he is correct in saying that open Foam treats `#include` like calling a function.  In OpenFoam using `#include Foo.H` would run through the code not the class declaration that is done in a different hierarchy level. I would recommend all openFoam related question not be asked in a C++ forum because there is so much stuff built onto C++ in openFoam a lot the rules need to be broken to produce a working code.

Answer (score 0):

You're only including declarations of classes. To execute their code, you need to create class instances (objects).

Also, you shouldn't write `#include` inside a function or a class method. More often than not it won't compile.

Comment: "Also, you can't write #include inside a function. It won't compile." just plain wrong

Comment: @user1233963: not from my experience. Maybe it depends on the contents of a file being included. But regular class headers can't be included like this, that's for sure.

Comment: On the other hand, your interpretation of it can be

Comment: `int main( void ) { \n #include "/dev/null" \n }` compiles just fine for me in `gcc`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It probably depends on the content of your file. A header file may well contain content which would not compile if included at this point but `#include` is a _pre-processor directive_ and will blindly include the file whatever it is. If it simply contained a valid C++ comment or generic code, regardless of why you might do this, it probably would compile fine.

Comment: I am working with the multiphaseEulerFoam Solver in OpenFoam and inside the main() of multiphaseEulerFoam.C are classes included. I assume that the classes have the right structure to be called in main().